# Eclipse Debug Perspective: How to search a value in Variables View

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, variables, perspective

Hi I have a java project and I need to know if it's possible to search a variable value (e.g. "myvalue") from the all variables values in Variables View in Eclipse Debug Perspective.

Would be great if you could search all the variables a specific value chain

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try the [evars plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/evars/).  You can use XPath notation to find variables/values when trying to debug.  As far as I know, there's not a standard way to do what you want in Eclipse without installing additional plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the evars plugin has not been updated for several years now, and when I have previously tried to get it working, I failed. For me it would be extremely useful to be able to filter the view of variables whilst debugging in eclipse, via xpath - it is a great idea. So I don't understand why this now out dated plugin seems to have been the only attempt to realise such an idea.

Can anybody else shed any light on this?